# Cannot get Sata 6gbs: ASUS P8Z68-V/GEN 3, OCZ Agility 3 60g in Raid 0

Tags: ssd, sata, raid-0

Setup:
2x OCZ Agility 3 60gigs (2.15 fw) - On the 2 new sata cables that came with my new mobo connected to the two sata6 ports and verified in bios

ASUS P8Z68-V/GEN 3 (latest/only bios)

Bios settings:
Sata mode: Raid
Raid 0 configured in the Intel raid bios utility
Fresh install of windows 7 64 pro

The problem is that I cannot get sata 6gbs. I can only get sata 3gbs as verified by the Intel Rapid storage utility version 10.8.0.1003

All parts are new, and all cables, softwares and firmwares are the latest and greatest.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that the speeds you're getting don't reach 6Gbps (which can be a result of other factors), or that the Rapid Storage utility is telling you this only support SATA II rather than SATA III?

Comment: Rapid Storage Utility reports that it is only connected at 3gbs. And speeds are consistent with that.

Comment: What if you're NOT in RAID?

Comment: I cannot verify that, but it is a good step to look at. I would have to break my array, go back to a single disk and re-image the drive. I was hoping to avoid that step if possible since this is my system drive.

Comment: I agree that's it's probably a huge pain, but I can't think of another test offhand (at least one that has any reasonable chance of success) that wouldn't require swapping hardware.  If you have a hard drive you can clone your current install onto, that might help simplify the process at least.

Comment: Agreed. I will probably have to do that. I just wanted to make sure, however, that this wasn't a common problem with the OCZ's or my mobo.

Comment: Could you share your experience please ? Were you successful in the end ? Any tips ? I've ordered exactly the same motherboard and SSD and I'm getting a little nervous that I'm in for a headache ! Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Jason- I havn't broken raid yet and tested single disk, as directed I believe this is the next logical step. How has your setup gone? The drive is still very fast at sata 3gps, just not a benchmark queen, which is probably all that is to be gained, but who knows.